# How can I enumerate all patterns of factorial?

Tags: python, factorial

I'm trying to make a function that will calculate all distances of each route. For example: A is at (0,0), B is at (1,0), C is at (0,1). Then there are 6 route to go through all towns like ABC or ACB or BAC or BCA or CAB or CBA.
Here, my question is, how can I enumerate all patterns of factorial like ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CAB,CBA. It would be easy if it's 2! or 3!, but if for example 8!, it would be super hard. If you know, I want to know  your advice!

Comment: `itertools.permutations`

Comment: Yes, thank you Pani and kaya3! It's actually don't think about the way back so It's would not be same route. I appreciate you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a bultin function `itertools.permutations`. You can use it like so

```
from itertools import permutations

data = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(list(permutations(data)))
```

Output:

`[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a')]`

You can make data contain tuples like `data = [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)]`
Then the output will look like this

`[((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)), ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)), ((1, 0), (0, 0), (0, 1)), ((1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)), ((0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0)), ((0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0))]`

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools

string = 'ABC';

result = itertools.permutations(string, 3)

for val in result:
    print(''.join(val))
```

Comment: Thank you starboy_jb ! It helped me. I cannot decide two answers only because it’s spec but I appreciated !